# textview getting pushed off into the screen

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

I had an issue with handling the textview's in a tablelayout that get generated dynamically(showing as a passbook statement) . Here I am using two tablelayout's, one as a fixed header and another one as scrollable. I am using screen-width concept to allocate certain percent of screen width to each text-view.

```
screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
```

The main issue that the textview in going inside the screen as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Statement]

Seeking your help in this regard. Thanks for your kind help!!

XML Layout

```
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp">
      <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tbl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:text='ewe'   
        android:layout_below="@id/ScrollView1" >       
      </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

   <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ScrollView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:gravity="left">
  </TableLayout>
```

Java Class

```
                    TableLayout t2 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl);

        // t4 header fixed
        TableLayout t4 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout);
        t4.removeAllViews();
        TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);         
        TableRow tr_head = new TableRow(this);
        tr_head.setId(10);
        tr_head.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams trlp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);          
        tr_head.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TextView label_dateval = new TextView(this);
        label_dateval.setId(20);
        label_dateval.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
        label_dateval.setText("TxnDate");
        label_dateval.setClickable(true);
        label_dateval.setWidth(20* screenWidth / 100);

        label_dateval.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);   
        label_dateval.setPadding(15, 0, 5, 0);          
        tr_head.addView(label_dateval);// add the column to the table row
                                        // here

        TextView label_narr = new TextView(this);
        label_narr.setId(21);// define id that must be unique
        label_narr.setText("DatVal"); // set the text for the header
        label_narr.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);
        //label_narr.setLayoutParams(trlp);     
        label_narr.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);      
        label_narr.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
        label_narr.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        tr_head.addView(label_narr);

        TextView label_dr = new TextView(this);
        label_dr.setId(22);// define id that must be unique
        label_dr.setText("Narration");
        label_dr.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);  
        //label_dr.setLayoutParams(trlp);
        label_dr.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
        label_dr.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);// set the color
        label_dr.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);     // set the padding (if required)
        tr_head.addView(label_dr);

        TextView label_cr = new TextView(this);
        label_cr.setId(22);// define id that must be unique
        label_cr.setText("DR."); // set the text for the header
        label_cr.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);          
        label_cr.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
        label_cr.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);// set the color
        label_cr.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);    
        tr_head.addView(label_cr);

        TextView label_runbal = new TextView(this);
        label_runbal.setId(22);// define id that must be unique
        label_runbal.setText("CR."); // set the text for the header
        label_runbal.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);
        //label_runbal.setLayoutParams(trlp);
        label_runbal.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
        label_runbal.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);// set the color            
        label_runbal.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);    

        tr_head.addView(label_runbal);
        t4.addView(tr_head, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



        int rowCount = DATPost.length;
        Log.d("Fill Table", "rowCount = " + rowCount);          
        for (int k = 0; k < rowCount; k++) {

            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);               
            tr.setId(100 + count);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            // Create two columns to add as table data
            // Create a TextView to add date
            TextView labelvalDate = new TextView(this);
            labelvalDate.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
            labelvalDate.setId(200 + count);
            labelvalDate.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);              
            labelvalDate.setClickable(true);
            labelvalDate.setText(DATPost[k]);
            labelvalDate.setPadding(15, 0, 5, 0);
            labelvalDate.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelvalDate);

            TextView labelnarr = new TextView(this);
            labelnarr.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
            labelnarr.setId(200 + count);
            labelnarr.setText(DatVal[k]);               
            labelnarr.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);             
            labelnarr.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);               
            labelnarr.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelnarr);

            TextView labeldr = new TextView(this);
            labeldr.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
            labeldr.setId(200 + count);
            labeldr.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);               
            labeldr.setText(Narration[k]);              
            labeldr.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
            labeldr.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labeldr);

            TextView labelcr = new TextView(this);
            labelcr.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
            labelcr.setId(200 + count);
            labelcr.setText(Credit[k].trim());
            labelcr.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
            labelcr.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);               
            labelcr.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(labelcr);

            TextView Runnbal = new TextView(this);
            Runnbal.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
            Runnbal.setId(200 + count);
            Runnbal.setText(Debit[k]);
            Runnbal.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);               
            Runnbal.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
            Runnbal.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            Runnbal.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            tr.addView(Runnbal);                
            t2.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        }
```

Comment: label_dr.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);    change this line with label_dr.setWidth(15 * screenWidth / 100);

Comment: your label_dr taking too much space. reduce it and then try

Comment: the main problem is you are dividing 5 labels thats good. but you also give padding. thats why your last label is going outside. Hope you understand this

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply same width to each **TextView** then I think **layout_weight** would be more suitable rather than width.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                     0,
                                     LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                     1.0f);
label_dr.setLayoutParams(param);
```

The last parameter is the weight.

And I also suggest you to create on method which would create TextView and return so that you don't need to repeat same code for every TextView.

Full Sample Code Step By Step:

1. MainActivity.java

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
   {
       TableLayout tableLayout;
       private Button button;
       String[] DATPost={"03-AUG-2014","03-AUG-2014","03-AUG-2014","03-AUG-2014"};
       String[] DatVal={"31-AUG-2014","31-AUG-2014","31-AUG-2014","31-AUG-2014"};
       String[] Narration={"Principle","Interest","Interest","Interest"};
       String[] Credit={"0.00","0.00","0.00","0.00"};
       String[] Debit={"30","22","23","152"};

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
   addHeaderRow();
   addRows();

    }

    private void addHeaderRow()
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
           TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       TextView tvTxnDate = getTextView("TxnDate", -1,true,R.drawable.header_background);

       tr.addView(tvTxnDate);

       TextView tvDatVal = getTextView("DatVal", -1,true,R.drawable.header_background);
       tr.addView(tvDatVal);

       TextView tvNarration = getTextView("Narration", -1,true,R.drawable.header_background);
      tr.addView(tvNarration);

      TextView tvDebit = getTextView("DR.", -1,true,R.drawable.header_background);
      tr.addView(tvDebit);

      TextView tvCredit = getTextView("CR.", -1,true,R.drawable.header_background);
      tr.addView(tvCredit);

      tableLayout.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
           TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      }

     private void addRows() {
   int count=200;
   for(int k=0;k<DATPost.length;k++) {

       TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
       tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
               TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

       TextView labelvalDate = getTextView(DATPost[k], count,false,R.drawable.cell_background);
       labelvalDate.setClickable(true);

       tr.addView(labelvalDate);

       TextView labelnarr = getTextView(DatVal[k], count,false,R.drawable.cell_background);
       tr.addView(labelnarr);

       TextView labeldr = getTextView(Narration[k], count,false,R.drawable.cell_background);
       tr.addView(labeldr);

       TextView labelcr = getTextView(Credit[k].trim(), count,false,R.drawable.cell_background);
       tr.addView(labelcr);

       TextView Runnbal = getTextView(Debit[k], count,false,R.drawable.cell_background);
       tr.addView(Runnbal);

       tableLayout.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
               TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
   }
   }
   public TextView getTextView(String value, int count,boolean boldFlag,int background)
   {
          TextView textview = new TextView(this);
          textview.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
           0, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
          textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
          if(count!=-1)
              textview.setId(200 + count);
          textview.setText(value);
          textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
          if(boldFlag)
              textview.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
          textview.setBackgroundResource(background);
          return textview;
          }
   }
   ```
2. activity_main.xml

   ```
   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   ```
3. cell_background.xml inside drawable folder

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#cebcbc" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
   ```
4. header_background.xml inside drawable folder

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#e1ecbb" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
   ```

It's complete working sample code and no TextView push off ...

[image]

**For Two TableLayout**

you only need minor changes for two TableLayout . As you have mentioned in you Question t4 is your header TableLayout and t2 is your row TableLayout So in my code inside addHeaderRow() method

```
 private void addHeaderRow()
{
 ....
 ....

 t4.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}
```

and inside addRows() method

```
private void addHeaderRow()
{
 ....
 ....

 t2.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
    TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

}
```

and Layout will be the same you have implemented also the other code remain same.

Comment: The column itself is getting vanished

Comment: Its looking much better. let me give a try and come back.

Comment: Now all the columns got vanished. Anything i am missing or any other information is required to check with the issue?

Comment: let me try one more time and get back to you.

Comment: It was good and working fine. But in my case it might fail and still show empty columns for addRows section as I am trying to use to separate tablelayouts , one for header and one for rows. This is because I have to scroll the row section. If I am using a single tablelayout, then your code is working fine, but not scrolling.

Comment: Do you want to scroll horizontally?

Comment: No the second table layout should scroll vertically.

Comment: its helpful, but still the issue is not fixed.

Comment: Hi sodhankit, I tried that before and already mentioned in my comments. if  I am changing it to t2, then t2 is getting vanished. I do not able to understand, what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your padding if you want 5 equal labels. the main problem is padding. if you want padding also you need to change your label width according to that.

```
label_dr.setWidth(20 * screenWidth / 100);
```

change this line with

```
label_dr.setWidth(15 * screenWidth / 100);
```

you need to statically check this width if you want padding. If you want to use padding then this issue comes on different device.

Hope it helps

Comment: Better than before. but still not completely solved the issue. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: reduce your width of cr label and narration. if this helps please mark this as a correct answer so others getting help from this. Happy to help you bro :) :)

Comment: My main issue is for the last column when i am giving the gravity as right. Why it is pushing the text into the screen.

Comment: if you reduce the other labels width then last label automatically comes in to screen please check. reduce other labels width. and also reduce cr label width to 10 or 15. @BasatiNaveen please do this